# Issues getting simple WCF service working

Tags: c#, wcf

I am having a frustrating time getting both POST and GET running on my webservice. I need to stop, chill out and figure out what is going wrong.

I broke it down to a very simple method that just takes a string and echos it back.  This works on the IIS I have set on my localhost, it works on the production box, but the same configuration is breaking on my test system.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong.  When accessing:

http://test.softwaredesignexcellence.com/WebPostService/WebPostSvc.svc/json/Test?testtext=test%20me

I am getting a page with a bold header with the text "Service" and the sub header in smaller text stating "Endpoint not found.". 
Why am I getting this message?  The same service works on my local host using the query string "http://localhost/Services/WebPostSvc.svc/json/Test?testtext=test%20me".  and I'm getting the response:

```
<string>Echoing test me</string>
```

The production server, which I can't put a link to, since it is internal is giving a slightly different response, but it's still working fine:

```
 <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Echoing test me</string>
```

It is frustrating when I publish locally, hit the local web server, everything is working.  I copy the published folder to the production server, type in the similar URL on that server, everything is working, then I ftp the same code, and the same settings to my test server, and it is breaking with the error listed above (Endpoint not found.).  **What am I not understanding that is keeping me from getting a simple service to run on the test server?**

The Interface for the web service:

```
    [ServiceContract( Namespace="http://services.alorica.com/WebPostSvc/1.0" )]
    public interface IWebPostSvc
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string Test(string testtext);
    }
```

This is the simple method I am trying to get working:

```
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://services.alorica.com/WebPostSvc/1.0")]
    [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://services.alorica.com/WebPostSvc/1.0")]
    public class WebPostSvc : IWebPostSvc
    {
        public string Test(string testtext)
        {
             return String.Format("Echoing {0}", testtext);
        }
    }
```

My settings are getting unweildy, as I have been fiddling with them trying to get everything working. 
 UPDATE - I just removed the serviceHostingEnvironment section, it didn't seem to be necessary, Web Service is still up and working with SOAP, but json is still giving me "Endpoint not found".

```
 <system.serviceModel>

    <!-- Set up Custom Behaviors -->
    <behaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <webHttp/>

        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>


      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SvcMetaBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>


    <!-- Set up the binding configuration  -->
    <bindings>

      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SOAPBinding">
          <security mode="None">

          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="JSONBinding"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                 openTimeout="00:10:00"
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2000000"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
          <security mode="None">

          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>


    </bindings>

    <services>

      <!-- -->
      <service  behaviorConfiguration="SvcMetaBehavior"
               name="WebPostService.WebPostSvc"
      >

        <endpoint address="soap"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="SOAPBinding"
                  contract="WebPostService.IWebPostSvc"
        />

        <endpoint address="json"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="JSONBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
                  contract="WebPostService.IWebPostSvc"

        />

        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />

      </service>

    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, those that answered so quickly.  I found my particular issue, it wasn't in the configuration as I had thought.

The server I was publishing to did not have .NET 3.5 installed, which is fine, because .NET 2.0 will suffice, but it was missing assemblies.  I don't know why I didn't get a better error message, but the solution was to look through my references, and switch them to "Copy Local"  and do a republish, after which everything was working on that server.  I did the "Copy Local" on all the references out of frustration, but I'm sure I only needed to do this to the ones that were not included in the .NET 2.0 framework.

Answer (score 1):

Your service does not have any host defined in the endpoints.

```
 <services>
  <service name="WebPostService.WebPostSvc">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SOAPBinding" name="serviceBasicHttpBinding" contract="WebPostService.IWebPostSvc">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://test.softwaredesignexcellence.com" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
     </services>
```

Comment: You mean the service doesn't have the `host` attribute defined for any of the existing endpoints?

Comment: I have 3 enpoints defined. toward the end after the binding and behavior configurations

Comment: I think my soap binding has always worked, My json isn't yet, I've made those changes.  I'm hitting my SOAP interface with SoapUI to test it to make sure that is at least working.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, it turned out to be a server issue, not a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [UriTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.uritemplate.aspx) to WebGet. Actually you should use [WebInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.aspx) for POST.